# Task throughput not increasing with multiple worker containers and multiple users

Tags: python, multithreading, docker, concurrency, celery

We're running a large number of background tasks per-user, but increasing the number of threads processing these tasks doesn't give the expected speedup to number of tasks that are executed per minute - **strangely, this is only the case when multiple users' tasks are involved**

A "worker" in this case is a Python 3.6 container, running 5 threads with the `threading` module, each consuming tasks from the same Google Cloud PubSub topic

Here is an example of a test case that demonstrates this problem

- Test 1: 800 tasks in a task queue, all tasks belong to 1 user (A)
- Test 2: 2000 tasks in another task queue, all tasks belong to another user (B)
- Test 3: We run both task queues from 1 and 2 simultaneously, (with fair consumption across both queues) for a total of 2800 tasks.
- We run test 1 with 1 worker container, this takes ~30 minutes
- We run test 1 with 2 worker containers, this takes ~15 minutes to complete
- We run test 2 with 1 worker containers, this takes ~120 minutes to complete
- We run test 2 with 2 worker containers, this takes ~70 minutes to complete
- We run test 3 with 2 worker containers, this takes ~200 minutes to complete
- **We run test 3 with 4 worker containers, this takes more than 200 minutes to complete**

As far as I can tell there are no “dead” threads (deadlocked or otherwise), but is there a possible scenario where a thread is executed much slower than expected?
Why did throughput not increase when we had 4 worker containers/20 threads available? What else could we debug to understand why the throughput has not increased? Again, it only seems to occur when there are multiple task queues being executed on simultaneously.

Some more information on what the worker containers are talking to, and what we've found so far:

Worker containers are all talking to (over HTTP/S):

- a database instance managed by Google cloud SQL (reading and writing). We don't see any significant degradation in performance with up to 100 threads concurrently reading or writing
- an elastic search node (reading and writing). Each user has their own index, which is appended by each task; We observed that there was a loss in indexing performance when multiple indices were being written concurrently; using bulk-write mode didn't improve this however.
- another backend service that completes part of the task, having looked at this we didn’t find that it was acting as a bottleneck, as it is scaled independently
- Google Pub-Sub for pulling and acking tasks
- Third party APIs - we aren’t running into any of the rate limits

Comment: Python isn't good at multi-threading because of the https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock .
That's a reason why `multiprocessing` was created.

Comment: Why don't you launch Multiple container?

Comment: We could switch to the `mutliprocessing` module, but this wouldn't address the fact that the slowdown only occurs when there are multiple users - we still get a good performance increase for a single user with the `threading` module

Comment: We are using multiple containers, sorry if this was unclear, but a 'worker' as mentioned in the post maps to a separate container. I edited the post to make this a bit clearer